# Show current file in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mountain-lion

Is there a way to open the folder that contains the current document?  For example, if I'm editing Foobar.xls that is located ~/Documents, to open the ~/Documents folder in Finder.

I'm hoping for a solution that works 'across' applications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In most applications you can right click (or command click) the Document title in the application bar on top. It will show a document structure from root folder to the current document's folder. Click on any shown folder to open it in Finder.

Comment: Another one to the list of MacOs useful hidden tricks.. in 2022!